# css not displayed correctly

Tags: css, encoding

I have the css made by one web designer, and that css file contains classes like :

```
    .icon-phone-alt:before {
        content: "\e064";
    }
```

and in my view page i have something like :

```
<span class="icon-phone-alt"></span>&#160;Tel.: (+40 21) XXXXXXXX<br />
```

The problem is that instead of something like this :
[image]

i get this:
[image]

I  have to mention that my browser is configured to utf8 and the original html page is displayed correctly with the same browser. I think that this has something to do with character encoding but i do not know how to handle the situation.

Comment: maybe you have online example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NFuLC/1/

Comment: This question has nothing to do with jsf. Please remove that tags and add the 'encoding' one if you want.

Comment: @XtremeBiker you are right, this does nothing to do with jsf. I assume that because my plan html files worked but not the jsf translation of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use special font for icon span which displays icons as characters. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<span class="icon-phone"></span>&#160;Tel.: (+40 21) XXXXXXXX<br />
```

Comment: i have that file locally, bu the problem is i guess that when i moved the layout to jsf project i did not moved the fonts directory as well. I`ll try later and update.

Comment: @VideanuAdrian and don't forget to encode relative urls in your jspf using <c:url> :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not included your Glyphicons/special fonts.

You should include them first. Try to look at this implementation:

**https://github.com/mdo/bsu/blob/master/step-4/bootstrap-less/glyphicons.less**